# Need a better mysql method for a secondary table index

Tags: mysql, sql

We currently have two tables.  One that stores info about a server and another stores the different tags for that server.  Here's a simplified example

### **servers**

server_id

server_name

### **servers_tags**

tag_id

server_id

tag

When a user on our site searches for "tag:example tag:example2" we do a query such as

```
SELECT * 
FROM servers AS s 
LEFT JOIN servers_tags AS st ON (st.server_id=s.server_id) 
WHERE st.tag IN ("example","example2") 
GROUP BY s.server_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT st.tag) >= 2
```

There's gotta be a better way to do this because in the example above that I provided is a very simplified version of some of the larger queries that have many left joins.  Where this solution hits a call is if the user does a search for

(st.tag='example' or st.tag='example2') and st.tag='example3'

in which case the having count >= 2 doesn't really help.  What are other ways that people solve this issue in mysql?  Is it the new json method?

Comment: why you are using the having clause.. ? ..

Comment: @scaisEdge because if the user wants to see servers that have both the tag example and example2 i need the having clause otherwise i'll get a "or"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need LEFT JOIN in the query but INNER JOIN. You don't need servers without matching tags.

You can use GROUP_CONCAT to gather tag list comma separated (plus add one more comm in the end). Then you can search the tag in the list.

When server has all 3 tags tag_list is 'example,example1,example2,'

The SELECT for `(st.tag='example' or st.tag='example2') and st.tag='example3')` case

```
SELECT server_id,
       CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(st.tag),',') as tag_list 
FROM servers AS s 
INNER JOIN servers_tags AS st ON (st.server_id=s.server_id) 
WHERE st.tag IN ("example","example2","example3") 
GROUP BY s.server_id 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT st.tag) >= 2
       AND (INSTR(tag_list, 'example,')>0 OR INSTR(tag_list, 'example1,')>0)
       AND INSTR(tag_list, 'example3,')>0
```

Comment: hmm, this is a really interesting approach (and clever), thanks for sharing.  since the user inputs the search tag, it may get a bit complex on how to calculate what the having count clause needs to be.  for example if the user puts in the following    `((st.tag='example' or s.server_id > 5) and (st.tag='example3' or s.server_id < 5)) and st.tag='example5'`   there won't be a lot of rows here so i was thinking of potentially using the json field... any thoughts on that?

Comment: You can put such search condition in the HAVING block. The only thing s to replace **st.tag='example'** with **INSTR(tag_list, 'example,')>0** leaving the rest as is

Comment: Ah right. Thank you for the help, this worked like a charm